# Distance from a compact subset need not be attained in a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Suppose we have a metric space $(X,d)$. Let $S$ be a compact subset of $X$. Provide me with an example of $X$, and $S$ (closed and bounded in $X$) such that $$\min \{d(p_0,p): p \in S\}$$ does not exist, where $p_0 \in X$.

Comment: Is $p_0$ fixed or not?

Comment: The question is not very well formulated. Since this is a question for a an example, it should start with asking for that, not with "Suppose" and "Let" (which would be appropriate for a question about a proof).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen This is interesting (to me, anyway). How would you word a question like this?

Comment: Just start with: "Can anybody give me an example of the following situation" and then describe the conditions that you would like to have satisfied. With "suppose" or "let" one usually introduces a situation that is given and one is not allowed to tamper with; here it is the opposite.

Comment: Instead of telling people what to do, tell them what your problem is.

Comment: This question seems to be related: [For any point $ a $ of a compact subset $ S $ of a metric space, prove that there exists a nearest point $ c $ to $ a $.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333479/for-any-point-a-of-a-compact-subset-s-of-a-metric-space-prove-that-ther) (It was in the list of related questions on the right.)

Answer (score 6):

I'll assume $S$ not empty.

Since the function $f\colon S\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(p)=d(p_0,p)$ is continuous, when $S$ is compact its image is compact, hence closed and bounded; therefore the image of $f$ contains its minimum.

If $S$ is only assumed to be closed and bounded, but not compact, the statement is not generally true. Consider $X=\{0\}\cup (1,2]$, with the metric induced by $\mathbb{R}$. Then $S=(1,2]$ is closed and bounded, but
$$
\inf_{p\in S} d(0,p)=1
$$
and there's no $p\in S$ such that $d(0,p)=1$.

Comment: This is slick! Actually I've been having a hard time looking for a counterexample in $\ell^2$ but  apparently I've gone the troublesome way.

Answer (score 3):

The function $x\mapsto d(p_0,x)$ is continuous on $X$, hence attains its minimum on $S$ since $S$ is compact.

Comment: No. $S$ isn't necessarily compact. And the min may not be attained either. See egreg or Antitheos answers for simple counterexamples.

Comment: @Vim: The question says $S$ is compact, does it not?

Comment: what I saw was "bounded and closed". But the OP seemed to have confused the two.